# Django custom manager return everything when user is on admin page

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a Django app. It's an article app. I have a field named `hidden` and I want to return a queryset **without** articles when `hidden` is true **and** the user isn't in the admin panel.

Admin-page -> Show everything

Normal search -> Show only with `hidden` = False

My "Normal Search" is a custom search I made. I'm filtering results with django-filter and I want to automatically filter out hidden articles.

I'm creating this with a custom manager:

```
class ArticleManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return super().get_queryset()
        return super().get_queryset().filter(hidden=False)
```

but I'm just getting this error:

```
TypeError: get_queryset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

Comment: The error message says you need to pass `request` into `get_queryset`. Look at the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset

Comment: How should I pass it? I'm on the admin page how can I pass request?

Comment: That error is telling you that your `get_queryset()` method doesn't get called with a `request` parameter. You can't do this in your `Manager`. You should do it in your `ModelAdmin`. It's even [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) exactly how you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the updated question: You shouldn't redefine the *model* manager's `get_queryset` function signature to take a `request` parameter. Instead, you need to create a new manager function with a `user` parameter which will return only the items you want. You will then use that as the `queryset` to your filter.

For example:

```
class ArticleManager(models.Manager):
    def get_visible_items(self, user):
        if user.is_superuser:
            return super().get_queryset()
        return super().get_queryset().filter(hidden=False)

# In your view:
user = request.user
artice_filter = ArticleFilter(queryset=Article.objects.get_visible_items(user))
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually no `request` instance would get passed to manager methods.
But you can customize the queryset used inside an admin using its [`get_queryset()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset):

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(hidden=False)
```

Note that this queryset will also get for editing instances, so you can really restrict which objects are accessible for certain users.

Comment: That's working but I want to hide hidden articles from my normal search (I have a custom search).

Comment: @Myzel394 What is your normal/custom search?

Comment: @malberts updated question. My normal search is just a custom search for users who arent admins.